# Ubuntu 11.04/10.10 or Scientific Linux 6/6.01

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-distributions, scientific-linux

I am going to install either Ubuntu 11.04/10.10 or Scientific Linux 6/6.01 but I don't really know which one to choose?

I want:

- the best environment for web development
- the least hassle to use/maintain
- attractive looking.

Please provide suggestions/reasons regarding why I should choose one over the other?

Comment: Any system will work for web development, as all you really need is Apache, `ed`, `sh`, and Python/Perl/etc for your executable scripts. So asking which is "better" for something like webdev is a meaningless question - virtualize and see them for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Scientific

I haven't used Scientific in quite a while, but back when I did it was kind of annoying with **fairly old packages**.

I used it because my understanding was that they test fairly heavily before releasing and so you're supposed to be getting fairly stable distro (there are probably other things they're going for with that distro too). It may have improved since I tried it last, though **I think Ubuntu's main trump card will remain their overall momentum**.

### Ubuntu

I'm a long-time fan of Ubuntu. Took me many years of switching between distros to settle on it. It's:

- Visually appealing
- Functional (massive number of supported packages ready to go)
- supported by most things with "Linux support" (defacto)
- has great documentation and a massive community (chances are someone's documented whatever obscure things you decide to try doing)

**----> [Go with Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) <----**

[image: Ubuntu]

Answer (score 1):

Use Ubuntu. Main reason for it is that it has bigger community. So if you face some problem, it will be easier to find solution or people who will be able to help.